# How do you populate the JWT subject field for the client credentials flow in Identity Server 4?

Tags: identityserver4

I know how to populate the the JWT subject field for the various user / browser auth flows but not sure how to populate the subject field for a client credential auth flow.  How do you populate the JWT subject field for client credential auth flow in Identity Server 4?

Comment: Are you asking how do you add claims to the access_token that is returned by the IdentityServer4?

Answer (score 3):

`sub` represents a human. The client credential grant type is the scenario where by definition no interactive human is present.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no subject field available for client credentials flow.  If you want to know the app that is represented by the token in this scenario, you have to look at either:

"client_id" or "client_sub" JWT fields.